Setting up multiple experiments on Firebase with level and session date condition
Objective

We would like to set two experiments at the same time, EXPERIMENT X and EXPERIMENT Y using Firebase.

Here are the outcomes that we want to achieve for each experiment

For EXPERIMENT X

Users become eligible to join an EXPERIMENT X IMMEDIATELY

If they reach level 10
If they have an active session within a certain date range - ex: Next 3 days
If they are not part of EXPERIMENT Y


Only X% of eligible users join an EXPERIMENT X


For EXPERIMENT Y

Users become eligible to join an EXPERIMENT Y IMMEDIATELY

If they are not part of EXPERIMENT X


Only Y% of eligible users join an EXPERIMENT Y





Concerns

Audience OR User Property calculations need to be instantaneous so that the player joins or leaves an audience instantly.

Potential Paths

We use Firebase events & audiences, yet, we do not know if we can use those features to achieve the desired outcome.
We have not tried Firebase user propoerties, we want to explore if this feature would be helpful or not.

We have concerns even if we pass the events and user properties to Firebase, the Firebase may not conduct its computation fast and users who check the condition may not be labeled.
Question
Do you have experience with such use-case? Do you know if Firebase can be used to achieve this outcome?

certainly you can achieve all of the above mainly by two ways 1st with the frontend flow and the backend support ,most importantly use security rules to ensure backend access accordingly . as this is wholesome job so should not expect all in the answer right away. please take your time to write some code and share with us if you face some issue with the code .
